# Drag And Drop List with Child/Parent functional

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I need to create somethink like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz0BA.png) using [react-beautiful-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd)

all list elements are draggable

Answer (score 1):

The solution I have seen for a nested list is to use the react beautiful dnd (RBD) [tree](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/packages/confluence/tree). Here is a link to the tree, and [another link](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1277) that describes considering the integration into RBD.